# DataGridViewCell.Value.get return null

Tags: c#

How do I handle Object reference not set to an instance of an object; DataGridViewCell.Value.get return null? Null is okay, but I do not want an exception:

`DataGridViewRow im_DataGridViewRow = vmpi_DataGridView.Rows .Cast<DataGridViewRow>() .Where(r => r.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals("HELP")) .First();`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [null-conditionals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?.` and [null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) `??`, to get rid of null exceptions from the predicate, like:

```cs
r.Cells[0]?.Value?.ToString().Equals("HELP") ?? false
```

**[FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault)**
**If you don't want an exception, if no item matches the criteria** you could use `FirstOrDefault`.
Also, like izzy mentioned you could simplify you code, by omitting `Where` and passing the predicate to First or FirstOrDefault instead:

```cs
.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Cells[0]?.Value?.ToString().Equals("HELP") ?? false)
```

`FirstOrDefault` will return the `default` if nothing is found, so `null` for `class` types and the default value for `struct` types

**[First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first)**
or **if you actually want to *throw an Exception*** if the item is not found, you can keep using `First`:

```cs
.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.First(r => r.Cells[0]?.Value?.ToString().Equals("HELP") ?? false)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Tried all, none is working. I am not able to add ? in the code. By adding .First(r => (bool)(r.Cells[0]?.Value?.ToString().Equals("HELP"))); I can add ?, but get still exception.

Comment: is it still the same exception? or you could maybe give us the full exception?

Comment: Exception is null

Comment: sorry i missed the fact that `?.` would return a "nullable bool". I've updated my answer

Comment: @RBrattas basically you just need to append ` ?? false` so `null` values return the concrete bool `false`

Comment: .First(r => (bool)(r.Cells[0]?.Value?.ToString().Equals("HELP") ?? false)); gives Exception = {"Sequence contains no matching element"}, which is correct; but how do I avoid exception?

Comment: @RBrattas um, `FirstOrDefault` will return the `default` if nothing is found, so `null` for classes and the default values for structs

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Int32 vm_ROW_Counter_Int32 = 0; vm_ROW_Counter_Int32 < vmpi_DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; vm_ROW_Counter_Int32++)
            {
                for (Int32 vm_COLUMN_Counter_In32 = 0; vm_COLUMN_Counter_In32 < vmpi_DataGridView.Rows[vm_ROW_Counter_Int32].Cells.Count; vm_COLUMN_Counter_In32++)
                {
                    if (vm_COLUMN_Counter_In32 == vmp_COLUMN_Index_Int32)
                    {
                        vm_COLUMN_Value_string = vmpi_DataGridView.Rows[vm_ROW_Counter_Int32].Cells[vm_COLUMN_Counter_In32].Value.ToString();
                        
                        if (vm_COLUMN_Value_string.Contains(vmp_COLUMN_Value_string))
                        {
                            vmpi_DataGridView.Rows[vm_ROW_Counter_Int32].Selected = true;
                            vmo_FOUND_boolReturn = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try FirstOrDefault() can return a Default value of something other than null

**DataGridViewRow im_DataGridViewRow = vmpi_DataGridView.Rows .Cast() .Where(r => r.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals("HELP")) .FirstOrDefault();**

Answer (score 0):

This work, thank you! You get `im_DataGridViewRow == null` and no exception:
`DataGridViewRow im_DataGridViewRow = vmpi_DataGridView.Rows .Cast<DataGridViewRow>() .FirstOrDefault(r => (bool)(r.Cells[vmp_COLUMN_Index_Int32]?.Value?.ToString().Equals(vmp_COLUMN_Value_string) ?? false));`